# Gitlab CI - ERROR: Job failed: executor requires OSType=linux, but Docker Engine supports only OSType=windows

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Getting this error while running Gitlab CI pipeline. As I understand the error says that I'm trying to run a Linux type docker image on a windows docker-engine? But the thing is I'm using a windows docker image. What could be the problem?

> ERROR: Job failed: executor requires OSType=linux, but Docker Engine supports only OSType=windows

My CI:

```
image: hello-world:nanoserver

stages:
  - build

build1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 9):

> > What's the difference between "Shared" and "Simple" tags?
>
> Some images have separated "Simple Tags" and "Shared Tags" sections
>   under "Supported tags and respective Dockerfile links" (see the mongo
>   image for an example).
>
> "Simple Tags" are instances of a "single" Linux or Windows image. It
>   is often a manifest list that can include the same image built for
>   other architectures; for example, mongo:4.0-xenial currently has
>   images for amd64 and arm64v8. The Docker daemon is responsible for
>   picking the appropriate image for the host architecture.
>
> "Shared Tags" are tags that always point to a manifest list which
>   includes some combination of potentially multiple versions of Windows
>   and Linux images across all their respective images' architectures --
>   in the mongo example, the 4.0 tag is a shared tag consisting of (at
>   the time of this writing) all of 4.0-xenial,
>   4.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2016, 4.0-windowsservercore-1709, and 4.0-windowsservercore-1803.
>
> The "Simple Tags" enable docker run mongo:4.0-xenial to "do the right
>   thing" across architectures on a single platform (Linux in the case of
>   mongo:4.0-xenial). The "Shared Tags" enable docker run mongo:4.0 to
>   roughly work on both Linux and as many of the various versions of
>   Windows that are supported (such as Windows Server Core LTSC 2016,
>   where the Docker daemon is again responsible for determining the
>   appropriate image based on the host platform and version).

I suggest you to try shared tags:

```
image: hello-world
```

the `latest`  tag has:

```
linux/386

windows v10.0.17134.1069/amd64

windows v10.0.17763.802/amd64
```

and Docker will pick up the right one for you

From [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) you need the executer `docker-windows` to run `Windows Container`

so you may add `executor = "docker-windows"` to your runners config

Comment: The executor was not docker-windows, but just windows. That was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The `hello-world:nanoserver` image is based from Linux. Hence the error message is thrown.

You are using windows docker engine. Use `winamd64/hello-world`

Comment: Im not so sure. From dockerhub: IMAGE nanoserver - windows v10.0.17134.1069/amd64